# convert single jpeg to single pdf in ubuntu 14.04.3 command

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to convert a single jpeg into a single PDF but can not do so, I tried 2 commands using imagemagik with no luck.  Thank you :).

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/scan$ convert -compress jpeg *.jpg my-jpegs.pdf
convert.im6: unable to open image `*.jpg': No such file or directory @   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: no images defined `my-jpegs.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

I'm using [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/convert.1.html) to do conversion.

I also tried:

```
covert input.jpg output.pdf
```

Comment: The error message indicates that you have no files matching `*.jpg` and not a problem in your syntax per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) then:

```
convert page.jpg page.pdf
```